# Query on Junit @parameters method's return type and the test class constructor argument type

Tags: java, junit4

The Junit parameterized test returns usually a collection of Object array but the test class constructor type can by anything?

For example:-

```
//Some class constructor
public parametrization (String username, String password, int pincode){
    this.username=username;
    this.password=password;
    this.pincode=pincode;
}

@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> getdata(){
    Object[][] data = new Object[2][3];  
    //row 1st
    data [0][0] = "usernamea";
    data [0][1] = "passa";
    data [0][2] = new Integer(111);
   }
```

As you can see the the parameters returned by the method `getdata()` are of type object actually but during runtime they get assigned to the arguments of the constructor which are some other subclass type of Object like String, Integer e.t.c  which is incompatible as per Java rules for eg:- String type object can't be assigned to Object type...

So is it the Junit framework that type casts the values returned as Object types to suite the constructor argument types say String?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested the values are being casted. The casting is actually done by the Java reflection API, specifically: [`Constructor.newInstance(Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29).

If you're curious, the above method is invoked by JUnit on line 186, [here (JUnit v4.11 source)](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/r4.11/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.java).